# How to add a secondary y-axis using autoplot (zoo object)

Tags: r, plot, zoo

I have trouble trying to add a secondary y-axis to my plot. Here is the thing, I have 6 time-series. In both cases the y-scale is in percentage. But I want to get the primary y axis in the left side of my plot with range scale from 0% to 0.80% , and in the right side(secondary y axis)  a range scale from 0% to 2.4% (for just one serie "percentISRA").

This is my data

```
structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.000113454034966788, 
0.000193020234641067, 0.00028445645011757, 0.00038617294713707, 
0.000487915939727557, 0.000589658932318044, 0.000729396573704041, 
0.00074661869484566, 0.00149766215004617, 0.0015524549908475, 
0.00151377145720633, 0.00147508792356515, 0.00143640438992398, 
0.0013901166274095, 0.00153218587904237, 0.000772955292406844, 
0.000700092472192302, 0.000684168634029051, 0.000668244795865801, 
0.000652294462131563, 0.000601581939262242, 0.000411502713000743, 
0.000395181441272686, 0.0003967976711029, 0.00041876249945121, 
0.000440727327799521, 0.000462692156147832, 0.000504634645020421, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.000236727931586416, 0.000377435080193467, 
0.000481619718431735, 0.000474768763872362, 0.000438198511659961, 
0.00046717781073689, 0.000443473985379896, 0.000493018083595849, 
0.000507877732422363, 0.000508713214685701, 0.000543696050597761, 
0.000604196901924348, 0.000613136562142067, 0.000626778793956288, 
0.0006552209972925, 0.000705958641598936, 0.000774468187192666, 
0.000845961598012603, 0.000919316940733693, 0.000931503046317525, 
0.000951685910707594, 0.000978421343134416, 0.00101577933576654, 
0.00107464502894916, 0.00106674375383016, 0.00108178243457025, 
0.00111024850882827, 0.00113987232279406, 0.00116272873042681, 
0.00115339519999924, 0.00109404015291951, 0.00109634369687414, 
0.00107495535093269, 0.00106611117440221, 0.00106180247301556, 
0.0011068588379313, 0.00116445937225801, 0.00121747668959727, 
0.00128044818133116, 0.00131713778815261, 0.00134916062976027, 
0.00134125935464127, 0.00127428948350427, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0000160762588918086, 0.0000157123929498129, 
0.0000361881218675691, 0.000131454841226435, 0.000141659626963313, 
0.000224141420269331, 0.000275049573426725, 0.00043415822624483, 
0.000619531384330623, 0.000762249530397923, 0.000919208066286054, 
0.00111791194933769, 0.00123200046151433, 0.00129134368878162, 
0.00132012217692128, 0.00132384353314624, 0.00138947171759345, 
0.00139053023669744, 0.00137341199806265, 0.00131989062586728, 
0.00126269751552996, 0.00117098675878606, 0.00105474812967944, 
0.000904570731801228, 0.000768203700357852, 0.000621086084264604, 
0.000559956606009332, 0.000554118211576402, 0.000616868547209654, 
0.000729336202008315, 0.000825677979832168, 0.000962838900603534, 
0.00112948950203755, 0.00124946602673012, 0.0013096527614084, 
0.00134699863854596, 0.00136249601980278, 0.00142564330010002, 
0.00145018771182373, 0.00146029326139461, 0.00142476671396703, 
0.00137880382974858, 0.00132974808502317, 0.00126729545788791, 
0.00123551240400009, 0.00115785280276624, 0.00108017847095552, 
0.00100251886972166, 0.000924844537910937, 0.00084718493667708, 
0.000769510604866358, 0.000691851003632501, 0.000711840396438712, 
0.000731829789244923, 0.000751819182051134, 0.000771808574857345, 
0.000791797967663556, 0.000811787360469766, 0.000831791483852842, 
0.0010979730078088, 0.00136416926234162, 0.00163035078629757, 
0.00189654704083039, 0.00216272856478634, 0.00242892481931916, 
0.00269510634327512, 0.00265909008283946, 0.00274488096250296, 
0.00296737159547644, 0.00325984719913695, 0.00356562451370683, 
0.00377064468251806, 0.00386536229176194, 0.00395542503871637, 
0.00421468319154564, 0.00437931211859222, 0.00457010255015157, 
0.00488956457062932, 0.00533699111233591, 0.00532246676354672, 
0.00547625398602045, 0.00540439823207152, 0.00529452285923325, 
0.00530203545343455, 0.00532279083623776, 0.00556689122547263, 
0.00577970386944561, 0.0059295580278963, 0.00606456376486676, 
0.00639558928818376, 0.00653953648531146, 0.00655699221889684, 
0.00643590687706409, 0.00634680161760589, 0.00635385756392437, 
NA, NA, 0.00017495026255787, 0.000384987857816134, 0.000454999382527596, 
0.000577037681514372, 0.000650260660906437, 0.000699075980501147, 
0.000638602143867448, 0.000653006862510075, 0.000712033580806984, 
0.000771060299103892, 0.000842216829764506, 0.000913373360425121, 
0.000984529891085735, 0.00101796466902574, 0.00105140246808963, 
0.00102528485217824, 0.00108424208462599, 0.00114274916961616, 
0.00126866961278409, 0.00139353266259529, 0.00165145507129434, 
0.00190937747999338, 0.00193812347367724, 0.0021457169797195, 
0.00225702726782121, 0.00241299278793985, 0.00245215561674949, 
0.00249131542443526, 0.00253047825324491, 0.00275373326546238, 
0.00269606001066209, 0.00276104136411936, 0.00294722718637353, 
0.00319449711228442, 0.00339025083385511, 0.00340254378690815, 
0.00338081284286527, 0.00350767587668264, 0.00373208495822089, 
0.00378793043307596, 0.0039015277119521, 0.00400283505889909, 
0.00409498537937674, 0.00398782611548119, 0.00398167812839273, 
0.0038886305341238, 0.00385605375536468, 0.00408285858813691, 
0.00435371442815078, 0.00440014305988314, 0.00449945948619559, 
0.000156668463203005, 0.000343451492438752, 0.00054567679204072, 
0.000742148669581035, 0.000905468858662011, 0.000890497128390052, 
0.000861751406267889, 0.00115536842508712, 0.00148658587507507, 
0.00182199540953917, 0.00209217097638973, 0.00234893615055384, 
0.00244819872225693, 0.00256664649689423, 0.00270265397232193, 
0.00275109821384477, 0.00265600633843173, 0.0025053051791514, 
0.00237361811731647, 0.00235755558955327, 0.00227499719119646, 
0.00195404607053785, 0.0016190001352375, 0.00142287046867483, 
0.00144043016946523, 0.00146949671437893, 0.00147024530089253, 
0.00150311894293253, 0.00183354503003468, 0.00228594794248109, 
0.00274102437819036, 0.00307998435154752, 0.00341115902516327, 
0.00354085698569064, 0.003657443988137, 0.00383171492850261, 
0.00392481770260809, 0.0039073007781899, 0.00385519915684348, 
0.0037850245182402, 0.00376260969920446, 0.00371316021293479, 
0.00348075618274177, 0.00317208188090617, 0.00286075544399383, 
0.00257577925236013, 0.00232910930203654, 0.0022111320674935, 
0.00210592358005383, 0.00206524325008631, 0.00208237518715465, 
0.00217485770386315), .Dim = c(52L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    c("percentCanada", "percentGer", "percentIta", "percentUK", 
    "percentUS", "percentISRA")), index = structure(c(18616, 
18617, 18618, 18619, 18620, 18621, 18622, 18623, 18624, 18625, 
18626, 18627, 18628, 18629, 18630, 18631, 18632, 18633, 18634, 
18635, 18636, 18637, 18638, 18639, 18640, 18641, 18642, 18643, 
18644, 18645, 18646, 18647, 18648, 18649, 18650, 18651, 18652, 
18653, 18654, 18655, 18656, 18657, 18658, 18659, 18660, 18661, 
18662, 18663, 18664, 18665, 18666, 18667), class = c("IDate", 
"Date")), class = "zoo")
```

This is my code:

```
filledstarter <- na.fill(z, list(NA, "extend", NA))

autoplot.zoo(filledstarter, facets = NULL) + theme_classic()+ scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x*100), limits=c(0,0.024), expand = c(0, 0),
                                                                                   sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . /2))
```

this is my output:

[image]

This is my this is my desired output:
As you can see here the scale is correct. Israel has a secondary axis on the right side of the plot. Is there a way to do something similar using autoplot? Thank you in advance.
[image]

Comment: One good article for your reference: https://blog.datawrapper.de/dualaxis/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did to do what you want. Some principle to understand:

- The 2nd Y-Axis in ggplot is just a reference - any drawing on the plots is based on it values to the main Y-Axis.
- To draw reference to 2nd Y-Axis, we need to adjust it values base on the different between 2nd Y-Axis & main Y-Axis. In your cases 2nd Y-Axis is 3 times bigger than main Y-Axis so anything that reference to 2nd Y-Axis need to be divided by 3.

Hope this explaination is clear enough. If need more guidance feel free to comment or ask me in message.

```
library(scales)
library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)

# convert percentISRA to 3 times lower than its actual values.
data[, "percentISRA"] <- data[, "percentISRA"] / 3
# Draw the plot
autoplot.zoo(data, facets = NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent, expand = c(0, 0),
                     # Here the 2nd Y-Axis trans formula is main axis times 3.
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 3, labels = percent)) +
  # I used coord_cartesian for setting the limits of main axis to between 0 - 0.8%
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 0.008)) + 
  # Added the X-Axis label format just to ensure it consistent in different system
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%m/%Y") +
  theme_classic()
```

Here is the plot output

[image]

One last note: This graph really confuse with everything is line and they are same units. 2nd Y-Axis only work best in case you draw two different thing on one plot. Though overall 2nd Y-Axis is in many case not really good practice.

Comment: Thank you very much! It help me a lot.It's very clear now.If I need more guidance I'll let you know.

Comment: Also how can I display more values for the secondary y-axis? And set the intervals ( for example 0.40)

Comment: May you review this questions and see if this help you understand a bit more about 2nd Axis drawing with ggplot. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66083557/adjusting-the-secondary-y-axis-using-ggplot/66083934#66083934