# adding second y axis plotting histogram (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-science, histogram, data-analysis

i'm new at R programming , how can i add a second y axis after plotting histogram so to plot geom_line
here's the code to plot histogram and geom_line, how can i solve my problem
I want to add a second axe y that can take into account the probability

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(x2, aes(x=X2, fill=as.factor(X1))) +
  geom_histogram(alpha = 0.5,bins=100, position="dodge") + 
  geom_line(x2,mapping = aes(x = X2, y = probability))+
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 150),xlim=c(0,20000000))+
  xlab("Intensity")
```

[image]

Thank you

Comment: May this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66158240/how-to-add-a-secondary-y-axis-using-autoplot-zoo-object/66159224#66159224

or this one
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66083557/adjusting-the-secondary-y-axis-using-ggplot/66083934#66083934

Comment: If you need more guidance with your specific usecase please share a sample `dput` of your data ;)

Comment: thank you for your answer i edited the question so to add a picture of my dataset

Comment: Please do not post a picture of the data as it makes it very difficult to reproduce your problem. Please use `dput(x2)` instead and paste the output.